# Ruby: How can I group multiple blocks?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have this code where `execute` is a [Chef resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html):

```ruby
execute 'phpbrew_0' do
    command 'phpbrew --verbose install 5.6 +apxs2'
end

execute 'phpbrew_1' do
    command 'phpbrew --verbose install 7.0 +apxs2'
end

execute 'phpbrew_2' do
    command 'phpbrew --verbose install 7.1 +apxs2'
end
```

Does ruby have this feature where I can provide a collection of `command` and have them all be passed to the `execute` resource. Something like Javascript's [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, `Hash#each`, for example: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html#method-i-each

```
resource_to_command = {
  'phpbrew_14' => 'phpbrew --verbose install 5.6 +apxs2',
  'foo' => 'bar'
}

resource_to_command.each do |resource, cmd_text|
  execute resource do
    command cmd_text
  end
end
```

Comment: The key is the resource name, not a host.

Comment: @coderanger: corrected. I myself don't use chef, so made a guess :)